# VBA RegEx for Negation

Tags: regex, regex-negation, regex-lookarounds, regex-group, regex-greedy

I am facing an issue with regular expressions.

I am trying to get numbers which aren't followed by centimeters or inches as shown in below examples:

1. `30.5 XXL Height 175.5 cm` - this should return only 30.5 as 175.5 has "cm" attached to it
2. `34 inches XL 54` - this should return only 54 as 34 has inches

How can I do this with a regular expression?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use negative lookahead `(?!)`.

**Regex**: [`\d+(?:\.\d+)?(?=(?: (?!cm|inches)|$))`](https://regex101.com/r/bAC5l4/1/)

Details:

- `(?=)` Positive lookahead
- `(?:)` Non-capturing group
- `(?!)` Negative lookahead
- `|` Or
- `$` Asserts position at the end of a line

**VBA code**:

```
Set re = CreateObject("VBScript.RegExp")
re.Global = True

re.Pattern = "\d+(?:\.\d+)?(?=(?: (?!cm|inches)|$))"
For Each Match In re.Execute("30.5 XXL Height 175.5 cm")
    Debug.Print (Match)
Next
```

Output:

```
30.5
```

Comment: Thank you so much Jovan :) for taking your time and helping me.